# Как при unfocusе применить свойства, которые применяются при classToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Добрый вечер. Помогите при потери фокуса на кнопе применить все стили, что и `toggleClass()` который удаляет класс. Буду очень благодарен, если вы перепишите скрипт более корректно, ибо я еще не очень силен.

Вот ссылка на сайт. [devinora.github.io](https://devinora.github.io/). В исходника в `main.js` есть весь скрипт с комментариями.

P.S Я пытался делать через метод `blur()`, но не вышло.

```js
"use strict";

//Other Libs


// Custom

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Меню

  $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass("user-panel__head_active")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("user-panel__head_active");
    } else {
      $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").delay(500).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).toggleClass("user-panel__head_active");
        next();
      })
    }

    // Пытался через blur это сделать, но не вышло.
    // $(this).blur(function() {
    //  $(this).toggleClass("user-panel__head_active");
    // });

    $(".user-panel__user-menu").slideToggle(500);
  });

  //Конец меню

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
p,
figure,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol,
dl,
li,
menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  background: #222;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page__inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.user-panel-header {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(https://devinora.github.io/img/header_bg.jpg) 0 0/cover;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.user-panel__head {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  transition: all .2s ease 0s;
}

.user-panel__head_active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  background: #5f8898;
}

.user-panel-header__avatar {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-panel-header__user-name {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-panel__angle-bottom {
  font-size: 8px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  transition: transform .2s ease 0s;
}

.user-panel__head_active .user-panel__angle-bottom {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.user-panel__user-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #5f8898;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.user-menu__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Toy</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="page">
  <div class="page__inner-wrapper">
    <div class="user-panel user-panel-header">
      <div class="user-panel__head d-flex_align-c">
        <img src="https://devinora.github.io/img/avatar_profile.png" class="user-panel-header__avatar" alt="Avatar">
        <span class="user-panel-header__user-name">Виталик Черный</span>
        <i class="icon-angle-bottom user-panel__angle-bottom"></i>
      </div>
      <menu class="user-menu user-panel__user-menu">
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Моя Страница</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Редактировать</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Помощь</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Настройки</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Выход</a>
        </li>
      </menu>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
"use strict";

//Other Libs


// Custom

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Меню

  $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (!$(this).hasClass("user-panel__head_active")) {
      $(this).addClass("user-panel__head_active");
      $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__user-menu").slideDown(500);
    } else {
      $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__user-menu").slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").removeClass("user-panel__head_active");
      });
    }

  });

  $(document).on('click', function() {
    if ($(".user-panel__head").hasClass("user-panel__head_active")) {
      $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__user-menu").slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").removeClass("user-panel__head_active");
      });
    }
  });


  //Конец меню

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
p,
figure,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol,
dl,
li,
menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  background: #222;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page__inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.user-panel-header {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(https://devinora.github.io/img/header_bg.jpg) 0 0/cover;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.user-panel__head {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  transition: all .2s ease 0s;
}

.user-panel__head_active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  background: #5f8898;
}

.user-panel-header__avatar {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-panel-header__user-name {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-panel__angle-bottom {
  font-size: 8px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  transition: transform .2s ease 0s;
}

.user-panel__head_active .user-panel__angle-bottom {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.user-panel__user-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #5f8898;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.user-menu__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Toy</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="page">
  <div class="page__inner-wrapper">
    <div class="user-panel user-panel-header">
      <div class="user-panel__head d-flex_align-c">
        <img src="https://devinora.github.io/img/avatar_profile.png" class="user-panel-header__avatar" alt="Avatar">
        <span class="user-panel-header__user-name">Виталик Черный</span>
        <i class="icon-angle-bottom user-panel__angle-bottom"></i>
      </div>
      <menu class="user-menu user-panel__user-menu">
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Моя Страница</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Редактировать</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Помощь</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Настройки</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Выход</a>
        </li>
      </menu>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял то вот так должно быть.

```js
(function(){
  $(function() {
    $(".user-panel__head").on('click', function(e) {
      $(".user-panel__user-menu").slideToggle(500);
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('user-panel__head')) {
      return;
    }
    $(".user-panel__user-menu").slideUp(500);
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
p,
figure,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol,
dl,
li,
menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  background: #222;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page__inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.user-panel-header {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(https://devinora.github.io/img/header_bg.jpg) 0 0/cover;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.user-panel__head {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  transition: all .2s ease 0s;
}

.user-panel__head_active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  background: #5f8898;
}

.user-panel-header__avatar {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-panel-header__user-name {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-panel__angle-bottom {
  font-size: 8px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  transition: transform .2s ease 0s;
}

.user-panel__head_active .user-panel__angle-bottom {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.user-panel__user-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #5f8898;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.user-menu__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Toy</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="page">
  <div class="page__inner-wrapper">
    <div class="user-panel user-panel-header">
      <div class="user-panel__head d-flex_align-c">
        <img src="https://devinora.github.io/img/avatar_profile.png" class="user-panel-header__avatar" alt="Avatar">
        <span class="user-panel-header__user-name">Виталик Черный</span>
        <i class="icon-angle-bottom user-panel__angle-bottom"></i>
      </div>
      <menu class="user-menu user-panel__user-menu">
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Моя Страница</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Редактировать</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Помощь</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Настройки</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="user-menu__link">Выход</a>
        </li>
      </menu>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: я задал вопрос. где же тут хамство? просто, как вы(ты) себе представляешь это на сайте?

Comment: стили к ".user-panel__head" не применяются. там должно добавлять еще ".user-panel__head_active" и убирать.